# Изменить имя файла при повторной его загрузке

Tags: файлы, загрузка

Как изменить приведенную ниже функцию, чтоб при повторной загрузке файла с одинаковым названием ему присваивался уникальный номер? Например загружаю один и тот же файл 1.png три раза, чтоб первый загрузился с именем 1.png, второй 1(1).png, третий 1(2).png

Сейчас идет замена файла.

```
    protected function _save_files() {
    if ($this->fetch_id()) {

        $this_class = get_class($this);

        foreach (array_keys($_FILES) as $key) {
            $uploadDir = BASE_FILES . '/' . $this_class . '/documents/' . $this->fetch_id() . '/' . $key;

            if (!file_exists($uploadDir)) {
                mkdir($uploadDir, 0750, true);
            }

            switch ($key) {
            case 'profile_documents':
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$key]['name']); $i++) {
                    $uploadFile = $uploadDir. '/' . $_FILES[$key]['name'][$i];

                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadFile)) {
                        $this->_message('errors', $key, T_('Ошибка загрузки файла'));
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так. Но чуть не то... Чем можно заменить uniqid() чтобы добавляло (1),(2) и т.д.?

```
$filename = $uploadDir. '/' . $_FILES[$key]['name'][$i];                    
if (file_exists($filename)) {
$uploadFile = $uploadDir. '/' .uniqid('file_').'_'.$_FILES[$key]['name'][$i];
} else {
$uploadFile = $uploadDir. '/' . $_FILES[$key]['name'][$i];
}
```